# Problems with convert string to bytes array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine, byte

I'm trying to convert a string into a texture, but first I try to convert it into an array of bytes to be able to use the loadtexture (texture2d), but the problem is that when I do the conversion, the debug does not return anything, any ideas?

```
public class Player : Manager<Player>
{

string ImageData;
Texture2D myTexture2D1;
Texture2D myTexture2D2;
public RawImage myImageRawProfile;

public void registerData(string response)
{
    data = JsonUtility.FromJson<LoginResponseData>(response);

    Debug.Log("load data user");
    Debug.Log("data.data image: " + data.data[0].image);

    ImageData = data.data[0].image;
    Debug.Log("data image: " + ImageData);
    ////the string return: data.data image: 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<message truncated> //////////////////////



      ///////////Problem is here///////////////////////// 
    byte[] myArraybytes1 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData);
    byte[] myArraybytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ImageData);

    Debug.Log("bytes array1: " + myArraybytes1);
    Debug.Log("bytes array2: " + myArraybytes2);

    ///////////the debug: "bytes array1: System.Byte[]"//////////////////
    ///////////the debug: "bytes array2: System.Byte[]"//////////////////

    //myTexture2D1.LoadImage(myArraybytes1);
    //myTexture2D2.LoadImage(myArraybytes2);

    //Debug.Log("my texture 2d1: " + myTexture2D1);
    //Debug.Log("my texture 2d2: " + myTexture2D2);
    //myImageRawProfile.texture = myTexture2D;

    premium = false;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the value of ImageData?

Comment: the imageData is a empty string

Comment: So then it is clear why the converted byte array is also emtpy

Comment: sorry, imagedata is a string that is obtained from data.data []. image

Comment: So you mean ImageData is what is written in the "// the string return" comment? Is the "<message truncated>" part also in this string?

Comment: ye, the image data is that string the data.data return

Comment: And what about the "<message truncated>"? If this is really part of the string, the conversion will fail.

Comment: maybe that's the mistake with the string

Comment: UPDATE. the message truncated it's because the string is too large to see in console

Answer (score 0):

put it in a folder called resources/textures, say you have a file `one.png` you want to load as a texture:

string texturestring = "one"

Texture2D myTexture = Resources.Load("/textures"+texturestring);

sav yourself a lot of code. load resources only loads from folders that are sub folders of a resources folder in your assets folder, so if you dont have one make one